# Swift - Delete class in array cause tableview to crash

Tags: ios, arrays, uitableview, cell, delete-row

I have a class called Offers, looking like this:

```
class Offer: NSObject {
    var Stores: String?
    var Headlines: String?
    var ImageURL: String?
    var PickedIDs: String?
    var Prices: String?
    var SetTime: Int?
    var Savings: String?
    var Dates: Int?
}
```

When the app loads, i get the data from my firebase server, and create an array of classes named usersOffers.

```
var usersOffers = [Offer]()
```

In my custom cell in the UITableView showing the data from usersOffers, the user have a delete-button, to delete the selected index of usersOffers and refresh the Tableview. To get and delete index, i am using this code:

```
  func deleteFromOffers(store:String, refresh:Bool, updateSavings:Bool) {
     //   UIApplication.shared.beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()

        if let index = usersOffers.index (where: { $0.Stores == store })  {
            print(index)


                if updateSavings {
                    userSaving = userSaving + Int(usersOffers[index].Savings!)!
                    self.ref?.child("Users").child(uid).child("Besparelse").setValue(userSaving)
                }

                usersOffers.remove(at: index)

                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "setSavings"), object: nil)

                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "refreshstores"), object: nil)

                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "updateannotations"), object: nil)

                if refresh {

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But for some reason i get a fatal error: Index out of range, when i use the deleteFromOffers function. The problem lies in the cellForRowAt, where i get the red line over first line trying to set the cell heading.

```
cell.storeTextLabel.text = usersOffers[indexPath.row].Stores
```

Can anyone tell me, what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you updated the numberOfRowsInSection accordingly?

If yes, could you paste the code of all your tableViewDataSource protocol methods?

Comment: We can't tell from the code that you posted. Post your `cellForRowAt` method, along with your other data source methods, as Kunal asked you to do. Why are wrapping the call to `tableView.reloadData()` in `DispatchQueue.main.async`? Is your `deleteFromOffers()` function called from a background thread? What do your notification handlers do?

Answer (score 0):

"Listed error happens when number of row count is more then actual array count."

First of all you just Debug "numberOfRows" method of tableview. It may be possible that you have deleted the row. But in "numberOfRows" you are passing wrong array count. That causes the error.